# Using jQuery to wrap elements in a hyperlink

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<div id="facebook">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i></span><br /><span id="soc_fb"></span>
</div>
```

And on a certain action, I want to wrap the whole thing in a hyperlink like:

```
<div id="facebook">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i></span><br /><span id="soc_fb"></span></a>
</div>
```

So, what I tried was:

```
$("#facebook").prepend('<a href="#" title="Facebook" class="facebook_c">').append('</a>');
```

But this does not seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepend()` and `append()` add complete elements, not just start/end tags.

[`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) should do it:

```
$('#facebook').children().wrapAll('<a href="http://facebook.com"></a>');
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, that's what I was looking for... It's been a long day!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `wrap` http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$("#facebook").wrap('<a href="#" title="Facebook" class="facebook_c">');
```

which wraps the entire `#facevook` `div`

or

You can also use `wrapAll` http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

```
$("#facebook").children().wrapAll('<a href="#" title="Facebook" class="facebook_c">');
```

Which wraps just the contents of `#facebook` `div`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/2K6bL/

Comment: That would wrap the `div` itself, not the contents (as in the OP's example).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this:

```
previous_dom =  $("#facebook").html();
$("#facebook").html('<a href="#" title="Facebook" class="facebook_c">' + previous_dom +'</a>')
```